# is there a way to set a default route with React-Router v6

Tags: react-router

I just can't find a way to set a default route with react-router v6

Is it because it's not good programming anymore?

Can somebody tell me why?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If I understand your question about a "default" route correctly then I am interpreting this as one of the following:

1. Use an `index` route:

   You can wrap a set of routes in a layout route and specify an [`index` route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes):

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route index element={<ComponentA />} />
    <Route path="pathA" element={<ComponentA />} />
    <Route path="pathB" element={<ComponentB />} />
    <Route path="pathC" element={<ComponentC />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route index element={<Navigate to="/pathA" replace />} />
    <Route path="pathA" element={<ComponentA />} />
    <Route path="pathB" element={<ComponentB />} />
    <Route path="pathC" element={<ComponentC />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

The index route is the route that will be matched and rendered when the path ***exactly*** matches the root parent route's path.

2. Redirect to a "default" route if no other routes match:

   You can also render a redirect to the route you consider to be the "default" route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/pathA" element={<ComponentA />} />
  <Route path="/pathB" element={<ComponentB />} />
  <Route path="/pathC" element={<ComponentC />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/pathA" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Remember that, if you are using TypeScript. You need not to set `path` if you are setting `index`, otherwise you get `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false | undefined'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708422/react-router-6-and-typescript-index-attribute-type-true-is-not-assignable-to

Comment: @AndréPena I can't confirm if non-typescript users see any errors/warnings (*trivial to test though*), but it's not a valid use case to specify both the `path` prop *and* the `index` prop.

Comment: can we set path for index route ?

Comment: @DennyJohn The "path" for the index route is that of the parent layout route. In the first example above the nested index route will match on path `"/"`. See more about [index routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes).

Comment: The patter `<Route index element={<Navigate to="/pathA" replace />} />` will not work when there are params in the "/pathA". In that case one must navigate from the component after the params are available, if I am not wrong.
My default route is ":userid/home"

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma In that case you'd need to make a special component that can read any route params and redirect to any route with them injected into the new target path, ***or*** you just need to specify a default `userid` value, ***or*** default to a route that isn't so specialized.

Comment: The last two options don't fit. I'm trying out the first one.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma If you still need help though, feel free to create a new post with [mcve] and description of the issue and ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: @DrewReese The first solution - "to make a special component that can read any route params and redirect to any route with them injected into the new target pat" worked. Thank you!

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma Great! Cheers.

Answer (score 18):

### TLDR;

use `<Route index element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />`

> `index`: default computed route.
>
> `<Navigate to="whatever you want"/>`: is used to navigate to a another already declared path.

### LR;

I found an easy way to redirect to a default component using `index` & `Navigate` combined.

In my situation I had used `React Router V6.6.2` with:

```js
createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(...))
```

The routes look like this

```js
/* All imports go here */ 

const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
            <Route element={<RrotectedLayout />}>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
                    <Route index element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
                    <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                    <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
                    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
                    <Route path="notifications" element={<Notification />} />
                    <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
                    <Route
                        path="*"
                        element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />}
                    />
                </Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>,
    ),
    {},
)

export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Now when you access your application, React router will figure out which index your application needs to point to, and since  your index contains a Navigation to a specific path, you'll be redirect to that path by default. you don't need to specify a specific component (element) in this situation because you don't wanna loose the link to it.

Comment: <Navigate> was just was I was looking for!

<Routes>
        <Route path="/" index element={<Navigate to="page/:id" />} />
        <Route path="page/:id" element={<MainScreen />} />
</Routes>

Comment: Just adding as an FYI for anyone seeing a "max depth" error, `path="*"` can do that, try using a specific path instead.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using **createBrowserRouter** you can set the default route in following way.

---

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Navigate to="/calculation" replace /> },
      { path: "calculation", element: <Calculation /> },
      { path: "calendar", element: <Calendar /> },
      { path: "profile", element: <Profile /> },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Try to make your post looking more different from other existing posts. Using the exact same introduction line puts you at risk to be misread as copying an existing post. If you take the opportunity to [edit] and add more explanation to your noticably different code solution it would help a lot and probably get you closer to [answer].

Comment: just looking for this! thanks!

Comment: Where does Navigate come from?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **createBrowserRouter** you can set the default route in following way.

As per docs  component loads children of parent. So

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Home />,
      },
    ],
  },
],);
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer here but I just wanna share my solution if it helps someone with theirs.

You can set `path='*'` to make a default route. The index route deals a parent route ("/") but doesn't deal with routes which should otherwise return a 404 status.

```js
if (!token) {
    // This router will handle my public routes. Anything else is going to redirect to AuthPage without losing the previous route typed.
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {/* Auth  */}
          <Route path="/">
            <Route exact path="recover" element={<UnknownPage />} />
            // Default route
            <Route path="*" element={<AuthPage setToken={setToken} />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }

  // This router is inside my application. Only logged users will get here.
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* My base page is just some fixed structure like Header, Sidebar and Footer. For this problem you can ignore it. */}
        {/* BasePage  */}
        <Route path="/*" element={<BasePage logout={logout} />}>
          {/* This is my specific users route */ }
          {/* Users */}
          <Route path="users">
            <Route path="" element={<UsersPage />} />
            <Route path=":id" element={<UserInfoPage />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Anything else is going to show this page. Even random words like:  http:localhost:3000/anything-asdvasd */}
          {/* Default Route */}
          <Route path="*" element={<UnknownPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Using parent routes like I used in my `users` routes makes it easier to scope your default routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the path a variable like this:

```
      <Route path=':default' Component={LandingPage2}></Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution using "createBrowserRouter":

```
    const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
          path: "/",
          element: (
            <Root />
          ),
          children: [
            {
              path: "/",
              element: <Navigate to={"/" + pageIds.home} replace={true} />,
                }, 
            {
              path: pageIds.home,
              element: (<Homepage />),
            },
          ]
        },
    ]);
```

The reason I use the "Navigate" component is so that I'm not duplicating my use of the "Homepage" component, which has a lot of parameters (not shown here).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet below: the default child element path set to emptyString "" becomes the default route.

```
 import { createBrowserRouter,RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
    
    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                yourObject: null
            };
        }
        router = createBrowserRouter([
            {path: "/", children: [ 
                {path:"", element: <Default/>},
                {path:"pathA", element: <ComponentA/>},
                {path:"pathB",  element: <ComponentB/> },
                {path:"pathC",  element: <ComponentC /> }
           ]}]);
        render() { return ( <RouterProvider router={this.router} /> ) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to navigate to start component from / then use this.

Ex: website is [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and you want your users to be directed to the start pages component.

// main.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
..other imports..

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "react-bootstrap/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "", // this right here
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "about",
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: "contacts",
        element: <Contact />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Reason for this is because Im rendering the component inside  with a fixed `<Header/>` and `</Footer>` components.