# React Router 6 and Typescript - index attribute Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false | undefined'.?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create an index route for one of my child routes in it's parent route but I keep on getting and error which says Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false | undefined'. How do I fix it?

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Profile />}>
    <Route index path="/username" element={<ProfileDetails />} />
    <Route path="settings/profile" element={<EditProfile />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: You can view this image for more clarity on what I'm trying to say]

Comment: Are you overriding the RRDv6 types somewhere? Seems the [`IndexRouteProps`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f16c5490dfa75f15dcfb86d2a981a7c58a9d1a33/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L217-L220) interface should accept `index: true` and only that.

Comment: I'm not sure, so I'll just leave it as a comment: is `path` allowed with `index` specified?

Comment: @DrewReese i tried index={true} and i was still receiving that error message. I don't even know what is wrong

Comment: @Caramiriel it's allowed and it's even in the official react-router-dom v6 documentation https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Comment: @MoroOwusuAfriyie I only see either <Route index /> or <Route path="..."> there, but not <Route index  path="..." />. I could've misread that though.

Comment: @Caramiriel thank you for the correction . It worked.

Comment: Interesting. Both `index` and `path` are optional props (see [Route and Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) for type declaration), but I haven't come across any documentation saying they are mutually exclusive, but yeah.... if a route is an index route it doesn't make sense to also specify a path as the route will inherit the path of its parent route.

Answer (score 19):

Fixed it. It was because of the path

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Profile />}>
    <Route index element={<ProfileDetails />} />
    <Route path="/username" element={<ProfileDetails />} />
    <Route path="settings/profile" element={<EditProfile />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: To clarify the answer. You need not to set `path` if `index` is `true`

Comment: Worth noting the same error on the `index` prop happens if you declare a route like `<Route>{children}</Route>` too, as opposed to `<Route />`. Not there is any reason to use the former syntax in v6 - I just had it left over from v5.

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need a path when index is true because whenever there is a profile page you will see your profile details. Purpose of ***index*** is to use when we want the path of parent to used.

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Profile />}>
    <Route index element={<ProfileDetails />} />
    <Route path="settings/profile" element={<EditProfile />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
</Routes>
```