# Set default route without using "/" in react-router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to make a route the default route without using "/"? I want the route below to be the route users see when they open my page, but I don't want to change the path name.

```
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. When users "open your page" they will open the `/` route. If they don't, and go directly to `/about` then the above will work. If you want to forward your `/` visitors to `/about` then use a redirect. Otherwise just serve the same component on the the `/` route as well.

Comment: As Christian says, you have to register `/` as a route for react router to know what to do with it. With that said, you can create two routs to the same component, so you only have to add one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

With a **Redirect**. If you are using `react-router-dom@5` (or below), you can use a `Redirect` component.
In your Route manager:

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/about" />
</Route>
```

Otherwise, when using `react-router-dom@6`, please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70437952/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-default-route-with-react-router-v6).

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6`. The `Redirect` component is a `react-router-dom@5` export and won't work.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer to include a reference to the (already answered) question.

Comment: rrd6 has `<Navigate />`