# Whenever user opens "localhost:3000", I have to redirect the user to "localhost:3000/home/dashboard"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Whenever user opens `localhost:3000` I have to redirect the user to `localhost:3000/home/dashboard`. How can I make the router to do that in a React application?

I tried but I am not getting the result I want.

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<AdminSignIn />} />
      <Route
        path="/assignment/:companyId/:frameworkId"
        element={<UserSignIn />}
      />
      <Route path="/company/:companyName" element={<CompanyReview />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: The router basically assumes it is running from `"/"` from wherever it is being served from, even `localhost:3000/`. *Why* do you need to navigate to `"/home/dashboard"`? Is that some sort of "default" route you want the app to navigate to, or is there something else with your specific scenario? Can you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: @DrewReese 
localhost:3000/ and localhost:3000/home is empty
All the code that i made starts from localhost:3000/home/*

I just want to defaultly display the localhost:3000/home/dashboard to the user when the user try to access the localhost:3000, since i dont want to display anything empty to the user. 
Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Can you [edit] to include an actual code example of the router/routing you are using? See [mcve].

Comment: So you basically just want to redirect from `"/"` to `"/home/dashboard"`, e.g. as a "default route", when the app starts from `"/"`? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438694/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese I've included the code where my routing logic is there
basically inside the admin signin page I have the dashboard page which is basically home/dashboard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/home/dashboard" />} />
      <Route path='/home/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
      <Route path="/*" element={<AdminSignIn />} />
      <Route
        path="/assignment/:companyId/:frameworkId"
        element={<UserSignIn />}
      />
      <Route path="/company/:companyName" element={<CompanyReview />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
```