# React Router DOM v6: Infinite Redirect Loop when using redirect in route loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a simple application using the new v6 APIs from `react-router-dom`. My app routes are defined below:

```
import { Footer, Layout } from "@org/components-library";
import { Outlet, redirect, type RouteObject } from "react-router-dom";

import { AppNavbar } from "./AppNavbar";
import { NotFound } from "./pages/NotFound";
import { OnePager } from "./pages/OnePager";

const AppRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <Layout navbar={<AppNavbar />} footer={<Footer />}>
        <Outlet />
      </Layout>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/one-pager",
        element: <OnePager />,
      },
      {
        path: "/",
        loader: () => redirect("/one-pager"),
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: <NotFound />,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default AppRoutes;
```

Hopefully the intent here is very clear but if the user hits the root route `/`, then they should get redirected to `/one-pager`. The problem is, when I do this, my app somehow gets into an infinite redirect loop that never resolves. This infinite loop for some reason also only happens when I deploy my app to my Kubernetes cluster and it does not happen in local dev when I run with `pnpm start`. I have tried making the `loader` function `async` to see if returning a `Promise<Response>` would change anything but it did not work.

Curious if others have encountered this issue?

Comment: Is there *something*, *somewhere*, redirecting the user back to the `"/"` route path? We may be substantially more debugging details/information for this.

Comment: @DrewReese nope, there is nothing at all -- this is literally a fresh new React app and I just have a single component called `OnePager` with gobbledigook text in it.

Comment: Are you really just wanting to setup `"/one-pager"` as a "default" route? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438694/8690857

Comment: Ok, so FWIW I've copied your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-infinite-redirect-loop-when-using-redirect-in-route-loader-5dj3ns) and the `redirect` from route loader works without issue. I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe with the information you have provided, and suspect the problem is elsewhere. Feel free to go ahead and fork this sandbox to add more of your actual code in to see if you can create a reproducible demo we could inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to redirect user when they go to '/' route right?, I don't think it's a good idea to use loader to do this, i would suggest to provide a component and use useEffect and useNavigate to redirect user [example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MlAD.png)