Set default route after login to a CustomRoute?
How would I set a custom route as the default route in react-admin with msalAuthProvider from ra-auth-msal? It seems to default to the first Resource route I have defined, but I want it to redirect to one of my <CustomRoute>s after login.
(Apologies: I'm not really sure if this is a ra-auth-msal, react-admin or react-router question!)
My current code in authProvider.ts:
import { msalAuthProvider, MsalHttpClientParams } from "ra-auth-msal";
[...]
export const authProvider: AuthProvider = msalAuthProvider({
    msalInstance: myMSALObj
});

My react-admin App.ts is below, but this always seems to try navigating to /users by default:
import {
  Admin,
  Resource,
  CustomRoutes
} from "react-admin";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoginPage } from "ra-auth-msal";

import { dataProvider } from "./dataProvider";
import { authProvider } from "./authProvider";
import { Layout } from "./Layout";
import { MyCustomComponent} from "./MyCustomComponent";
import { UserList, UserEdit, UserCreate } from "./Users";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Admin
        layout={Layout}
        requireAuth
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        loginPage={LoginPage}                
      >
        <CustomRoutes>
          <Route path="/mycustomroute/:id" element={<MyCustomComponent />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/mycustomroute/123" replace />} />
        </CustomRoutes>               
        <Resource
          name="users"
          list={UserList}
          edit={UserEdit}
          create={UserCreate}
          recordRepresentation={(record) => record.username}
        />
      </Admin>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


Well React-Router-DOM only matches content to a URL or whatever you say is the current path. You can kind of define a "default route" in the absence of a matched route, but that's not exactly what you are asking for. I suspect you can/should configure your auth flow to redirect/navigate to the path you want users to land on after they authenticate. Can you [edit] to share how you are handling/configuring your authentication flow? See [mcve].

actually a default route would also work fine in my scenario - I'll edit question

Maybe my answer here can address the "default route" aspect.

Sadly no - I'll try spend a bit of time creating a minimal repro - I'm pretty sure it's some sort of react-admin oddity (or possibly the auth library I'm using) but yeah it'll take a bit of time to extract into a minimal repro

@DrewReese sorry I did not read the answer you linked properly - it does work by using:
            <CustomRoutes>
                <Route index element={<Navigate to="/mycstomroute/123" replace />} />
                <Route path="/mycstomroute/:id" element={<MyCustomComponent/>} />                
            </CustomRoutes>

Feel free to add as answer if you want since you did get me there in the end :)

It's preferable not to provide duplicate answers, so we can either vote to close this as a duplicate of another post, i.e. the one that did provide a working solution, and you can upvote it if it was helpful, or we can leave this open to see if a better solution comes along.

Fair enough - though when using react-admin I doubt anyone will find that one as the use of react-admin kind of obfuscates the react-router bits of the puzzle.
EDIT: but yeah maybe there is a "better" react-admin specific answer so will leave open for now.

Oh that's right, react-admin does use RRD under-the-hood. I've taken the liberty of adding [tag:react-router-dom] tag back.

Seems this question was also posted as a GH issue, so I'll answer here as well.
ra-auth-msal has deep linking enabled by default, which means the user will be redirected to the URL they originally requested.
If you disable this feature, the user will be redirected to window.location.origin.
If you would like to set a default redirect route, you will need to override the handleCallback method in the authProvider.
This could be a feature though, so feel free to open a PR to add this feature (i.e. add a parameter to set a default redirect route).

Thanks - I actually ended up using the react-router approach here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438694/8690857
And TBH I'm not sure after getting that working if it makes sense to add this as a PR on ra-auth-msal.  I would probably argue a more obvious method of setting default route (including using a customroute as default) on react-admin might make sense? Or some extra react-admin documentation on how to do this?
